# Java Gson parse not deserializing correctly

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I have a `List<List<Integer>>`
with value

```
[[537316070],[306297332],[319303159],[538639811],[528406093],[166705854],[124574525],[967403337],[569514785],[304831454],[219384921],[308948513],[355538394],[297996417]]
```

after serializing it with Gson.

When I deserialize it using

```
List<List<Integer>> data = (List<List<Integer>>) GsonParser.gson.fromJson(datastr, List.class);
```

I am getting

```
[[5.3731607E8], [3.06297332E8], [3.19303159E8], [5.38639811E8], [5.28406093E8], [1.66705854E8], [1.24574525E8], [9.67403337E8], [5.69514785E8], [3.04831454E8], [2.19384921E8], [3.08948513E8], [3.55538394E8], [2.97996417E8]]
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I guess that because of type erasure, it compiles fine, but in fact it should give a Runtime Exception, but the JVM cannot detect that. I guess that the serialization/deserialization process converts it to doubles.

Comment: JSON doesn't know the difference between an integer and a float, and hence parsers have no hints.  Thus they will tend to cram a long int into a double.  I've run into this problem on iPhone.

Comment: Whats the solution? Should I just keep it as Strings instead of ints?

Comment: (Has nothing to do with "type erasure", except perhaps after the fact.  The "damage" is done before that cast has any effect.)

Comment: Odds are that the double values are exact, if you cast to long.

Comment: But its not even a long int, its just a regular int.

Comment: So cast to int.  You'll get the correct value, I'm pretty certain.

Comment: (Note that the objects inside the inner arrays are likely Double objects.)

Comment: can you show the code, i dont get you.

Comment: @HotLicks: Due to type erasure, you can compile this thing with an invalid cast. You will obtain a `List<Integer>`, while every object in the array is in fact a `Double`.

Comment: `int realValue = data.get(0).get(0).intValue();`, with likely some casts required.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux - Like I said, that only gets involved after the fact, and confuses the data type of `data`, without actually having any effect on the data values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Gson`, by default, parses any JSON number into a `double`. This happens in the `ObjectTypeAdapter#read(JsonReader)` method:

```
...
case NUMBER:
  return in.nextDouble();
...
```

Do the following

```
List<List<Integer>> data = GsonParser.gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<List<Integer>>>() {}.getType());
```

to get them as `Integer` instances.

The `TypeToken` is a Java hack to get the actual generic parameter types. The [javadoc](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) states

> Constructs a new type literal. Derives represented class from type
>   parameter.
>
> Clients create an empty anonymous subclass. Doing so embeds the type
>   parameter in the anonymous class's type hierarchy so we can
>   reconstitute it at runtime despite erasure.

Comment: Of course, what SHOULD be done is to make all numerics Number, and select the appropriate subclass of Number based on the character data, but apparently this isn't being done.

Comment: @hotLicks I disagree. What is the appropriate subclass of `Number`?

Comment: The appropriate subclass of Number would be based on the character value.  Integer or Long (based on length, or maybe Long all the time) for any number without a decimal point (and with a value less than Long.MAX_VALUE), Double if there is a decimal point, take your pick of integer types for `true/false`.

Comment: @HotLicks To be clear, this behavior is only important when you don't specify a type. Gson decided to go with a default. The [JSON RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) says that a JSON number can have an integer component and a fractional component. It is my opinion that defaulting to `double` makes more sense than going int/long some times and double others.

Comment: Except when the number is an integer of more than 15 digits.